# https using BasicHttpBinding and ignoring certificate errors

Tags: c#, security, x509certificate2

I am using `BasicHttpBinding` to connect a web service hosted on a secured (https) port.  To get it working, I have changed the `Security.Mode` to `TransportWithMessageCredential` and `Security.Message` to `BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Cerificate`.  I am also calling

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate()
```

with localhost as the subject name.

The issue here is that for unit testing, I have an unsigned certificate from the web server and am supposed to ignore any certificate error thrown during the proxy creation;  but I am unable to do so, because I keep getting an error telling me to **"specify a certificate"**.  Right now, I am clueless; I appreciate any help here.

Comment: If you are only using server certificate, then set the `SecurityMode` to `Transport`

Comment: Thanks @Tung; I could get RemoteCertificateValidationCallback method called and able to return 'TRUE' to ignore the errors! Please write your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For server ssl, the `SecurityMode` should be set to `Transport`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following code to skip certificate validation. This creates a [`RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) that always return true for any certificate.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: I already had the ServerCertificateValidationCallback but was not getting called; once I changed the Security Mode to Transport, it worked!